# FedEx Shipping Not Showing in magento onepage

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, fedex

I've configured `FedEx Shipping` and setup but its not showing in front-end in one page shipping method block.

I found error in fedex log and error is:

```
"SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Element 'Major' has fixed value '13' (value '10' is not allowed)".
```

**How can i fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error occurred due to Major Element so have a look into **Fedex.php** file from

> app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier

and find **Major** and you will see integer number which is version number of your Fedex **wsdl version number**

so check **wsdl version** from

> app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/wsdl/FedEx

here you will see files which is wsdl files and check its version number and change that version number with Major Element Value
Like

> 'Major'        => '5',

Hope it helps :)